# How to make navigation drawer text appearance colored?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

How to make navigation drawer text appearance like below image?

I want to design navigation drawer like this.

How to change text color, icon color and background color when I click on navigation drawer item?

[image: image of drawer]

Comment: @Cœur But it's clear to me what s/he wants to do: changing the selected item color. I'll either mark that for closing as "too broad" or "request for a tutorial"

Comment: @KlingKlang i understood the same initially, hence my answer

Comment: @BlackBlind, it would be better to provide a screenshot that does not display any email address.

Comment: @Cœur bro i circled that part where i am unable to make

Comment: @BlackBlind I've included the clarification from your comment in your question and I've retracted my close vote. Next time, it may be best to directly [edit] your question to include such details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below steps:

1. Create a selector drawable.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     <!-- This is used when the Navigation Item is checked -->
>     <item android:color="#E91E63" android:state_checked="true" />
>     <!-- This is the default text color -->
>     <item android:color="@android:color/black" />
> </selector>
> ```

2. Now add the below 2 attribute to your navigation view.

> app:itemIconTint="@drawable/navigation_menu_selector"
>       app:itemTextColor="@drawable/navigation_menu_selector"

You can manually tell which item should be checked (Make sure your menu group should have single checkableBehaviour):

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.any_id:
               menuItem.setChecked(true);
                break;
            case R.id.any_id:
 menuItem.setChecked(true);
                break;
            case R.id.any_id:
 menuItem.setChecked(true);
                break;
            case R.id.any_id:
 menuItem.setChecked(true);
                break;

        }

        return false;
    }
```

Hope it will work for you.
Thanks.

Comment: your code is good but it is change all item color when i am selecting anyone

Comment: Please check i had made changes. Which will help you checking and unchecking the items manually. You can check the items you want.

Comment: @Surendra Kumar great !! it is working. But i want something else can you help me out . in this code when i am click on navigation item it will change the color or selected item but when i am back and select second item now both item is pink

Comment: i want when i click on second item then first item will be black and second item pink plz help me out

Comment: @BlackBlind For navigation menu there is group and there you have to set checkableBehaviour="single". Is it done?

Comment: If i want to change click item background color so how can do that

Comment: I think for that you have to use ListView/RecyclerView.

Comment: see image of my question . I want do like that means when am i click on navigation item then background will be same color of background color how can do that?

Comment: Yes i saw it. For that you have to use the ListView/RecyclerView. Check this [link](https://www.journaldev.com/9958/android-navigation-drawer-example-tutorial). Here you can find your solution.

Answer (score -2):

use the following attribute to set the colour to whatever you like:

```
drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.PURPLE);
```

EDIT: I must have misunderstood your question. Do you have a drawer menu and want to change the shadow colour, or do you not have a drawer menu at all? If yes to the former, my previous answer should cover it, if yes to the latter, have a look at the following from the developers website:
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer

Comment: drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.PURPLE); does not remove the hovered background in the drawer, it just colors the empty space next to the navigation in the drawer.